# Cannot get a notification icon with libnotify

Tags: notifications, icons, libnotify

I put a 256x256 icon into `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/status/foo.png`. Then I tried (in Python3)

```
import notify2

notify2.init("a")
notification = notify2.Notification(
    "a"
    "b,
    "foo")
notification.show()
```

Now the icon is not picked up. Why?

I tried putting it into

```
~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/
~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/status/
~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/
```

but still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the icon in the same folder as the script, and it works.